# Showing left continuity of this distribution function

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\cal{A},\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $u$ is a nonnegative measurable function. Then the function $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{\bar{R}}$ given by $t\mapsto \mu(\{x: u\ge t\})$ is left continuous.

Is this true? I tried going about it the standard way, by letting $(x_j)$ be an increasing sequence with $x_j\to t$ so that ($\{x: u\ge x_j\})_j$ is a decreasing sequence of sets with limit $\{x: u\ge t\}$. However, I cannot use the continuity of measures from above to deduce that $lim_{j\to \infty}F(x_j)=F(t)$ since I do not know if $\mu(\{x: u\ge x_j\})$ is finite or not. At this point I have not used the fact that the space is $\sigma$-finite. Am I somehow meant to incorporate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of positive integers, $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(X)$, and $\mu$ counting measure on $X$. Note that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Define $u(n)=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then $\mu(\{n:u(n)\geq t\})=\infty$ if $0\leq t<1$, because there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $t\leq 1-\frac{1}{N}$, hence 
$$u(n)=1-\frac{1}{n}\geq 1-\frac{1}{N}\geq t $$
for $n\geq N$.

However, $\mu(\{n:u(n)\geq t\})=0$ if $t\geq 1$, because $u(n)<1$ for all $n$. So $F(t)$ is not left continuous in this case.

Comment: Yes, there's no issue applying continuity from below for the sets $\{u\geq t\}$.